# Romans 8:27-30 How does the Saints need interceding? And what are stages of Redemption?

Tags: romans

Romans 8:27-30 (DRB):

> 27And he that searcheth the hearts knoweth what the Spirit desireth: because he asketh for the **saints** according to God. 28 And  we know that to them that love God all things work together unto good: to such as, according to his purpose, are called to be saints. 29For whom he foreknew, he also predestinated to be made conformable to the image of his Son: that he might be the Firstborn amongst many brethren. 30And whom he predestinated, them he also called. And whom he called, them he also **justified**. And whom he justified, them he also **glorified**.

Romans 8:27 (KJV):

> And he that searcheth the hearts knoweth what is the mind of the Spirit, because he maketh **intercession** for the saints according to the will of God.

It's accepted that the Spirit and the Son of God intercede for the Sinners, but is it logical to intercede for the Saints?

Are all stages of Redemption assembled in these four verses?

According to these four verses what are the stages of Redemption?

Comment: What makes you say that justification, sanctification and glorification are 'stages of redemption' ? And when you say 'redemption' are you speaking of the _lutron/lutrosis/apolutrosis_ set of words or do you mean the _agorazo/exagorazo_ words ?

Comment: Why are you ignoring foreknowing, predestination, and calling?

Comment: This question is not an hermeneutic question. It is the opening gambit in a topical debate about doctrine.

Comment: @NigelJ I modified the question to fit with the requirements of the site. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions in this question should be challenged.

First, "redemption" as used in the Bible is an analogue for what is technically known as the atonement.  The Bible uses many words to describe this such as: forgiveness, reconciliation, propitiation (or sacrifice of atonement in some versions), redemption, etc, (each of these terms offers a different analogue of, and insight into the atonement).

Second, "sanctification" in modern theological usage is quite different from the way it is used in the NT.  In the NT it is almost equivalent to justification but actually means being set aside for a sanctified purpose.  The NT speaks of people being sanctified at conversion.  In modern terminology it denotes the Christian life of growing into Christ.

Third, "Glorification" as a noun does not exist in the NT, only the verb to glorify.

These three "stages" of the process of salvation: Justification, sanctification and glorification, are broadly correct but omit much detail.  So let me add some detail.

**Atonement**

This first phase of salvation is also called justification (= a declaring right or just), forgiveness, reconciliation, propitiation (or sacrifice of atonement in some versions), redemption, etc, (each of these terms offers a different analogue of, and insight into the atonement).  Atonement was accomplished by Jesus at the cross and decided upon by God “before the world began”, Matt 25:34, Heb 4:3, Rev 13:8.  This is why the atonement is sometimes called the eternal election – God decided to save all people (see “Election”) well before anyone sinned, solely by His grace born of His essential essence – love (1 John 4:8, 16).

This atonement is aimed at fixing the guilt and alienation of sin – it atones for wrong acts, without any input from sinners at all.  This means that Atonement is entirely “extrinsic” – done from outside a sinner.

The Bible also declares that God decided to make this reconciling atonement without reference to any human decision.  That is, Jesus died for the “ungodly” and “powerless” (Rom 5:6), not the righteous (Luke 5:32).  Paul makes the stark point that Jesus’ sacrifice was to demonstrate His righteousness (Rom 3:25, 26).  Therefore, the atonement was for all people – all are forgiven, all have been provided atonement!  (As we will soon see, this does not imply that all will be finally saved.)

While atonement is extrinsic and before conversion, the Holy Spirit still strives with sinners to bring them to conversion.

**Conversion**

“Conversion”,” commitment”, “deciding to be a disciple of Christ”, “sanctification”, “washing” (1 Cor 6:11) are all terms that describe what happens to a sinner at the point in the life when they realise their great need of God.  That is, the sinner’s life is “turned” in a different direction – toward God (Isa 45:22, Acts 2:38, 3:19, Rom 6:13, Luke 15:7, Isa 55:7, Eze 18:21, 33:11, Ps 51:13, Eph 4:22, etc).  This is the beginning of the Christian life and walk with Jesus.  In 2 Kings 11:17 conversion is described as an act of becoming a covenant people of God.

The step of conversion begins the process that is “intrinsic” that transforms the sinner to a person dedicated to serving God.

Note that a person’s decision to become a Christian by conversion is celebrated publicly by the rite of Baptism, Acts 8:12, 16:33.

**Confession or Repentance**

Confession or repentance ALWAYS immediately follows conversion (1 John 1:9, Luke 15:32, Acts 17:30, Mark 1:15, Isa 55:7), and in the Bible conversion and confession/repentance are often used interchangeably because one always implies the other.  While confession does not inform God of our sin, it is an essential first step toward reformation of the life (2 Cor 7:9, 10, Ps 32:5, Prov 28:13, James 5:16).  That is, God cannot reform the sinner unless the sinner recognises that he/she is a sinner and confesses!

**Christian Life**

In modern theology, this stage is often called, unbiblically, “Sanctification”.  This stage of salvation is aimed primarily at fixing the corrupt human nature – removing the tendency to evil and our enjoyment of sin.  That is, as we “grow into Christ”, He begins to break the power of sin over us.

While this is a single functional stage of salvation, it involves several separate logical steps:

- Consecration, on-going commitment and Christian character development.  The Bible has numerous phrases to describe this including: “reflecting the Lord’s glory and being transformed into His likeness” (2 Cor 3:18), being “transformed by the renewing of your mind” (Rom 12:2), “follow after righteousness” (1 Tim 6:11), walking in the “newness of life” (Rom 6:4), “perfecting holiness” (2 Cor 7:1), “partaking in the divine nature” (2 Peter 1:4), “growing up into Christ” (Eph 4:15), “pressing toward the mark” (Phil 3:12-15), “being built up in Christ” (Col 2:7), “becoming complete in all the will of God” (Col 4:12), “fighting the good fight of faith” (1 Tim 6:12), “growing in grace” (2 Peter 3:18), “produce fruit in keeping with repentance” (Matt 3:8), “walk by the spirit and you will not gratify the desires of the flesh” (Gal 5:16), plus many more.
- Perseverance of the Saints – a life-time commitment to serving Jesus and the Imitation of Christ.  The Bible calls this, “enduring to the end” (Matt 24:13, Mark 13:13, Heb 10:36), “remaining steadfast” (James 1:12, 1 Cor 15:58), “fighting the good fight” (2 Tim 4:7), “being strong in the Lord and in the strength of His might” (Eph 6:10), etc.  That is, the Christian life consists of much more than simply believing and being converted – it involves a lifetime commitment to Jesus called the Imitation of Christ and obedience to Jesus’ commandments.  Seven times in Rev 2 & 3 such people are called “overcomers” or “conquerors”.
- Discipling and teaching others (Matt 28:19, Acts 1:8, 2 Tim 2:2) or being “fishers of men” (Matt 4:19, Mark 1:17).

While it is obvious that the Christian life is lived by cooperation and consent of the Christian, it is still a miraculous work of transformation and renewal by God in us.  It is also God’s initiative.  “God is sovereign, Man is responsible”.

The New Testament makes an important distinction between the pre-conversion life and the post conversion life and describes these two lives as a “psychical” (or fleshly, Gr: sarx) life, vs a pneumatic (= spiritual) life.  That is the difference between a life controlled by the flesh and carnal desires, vs, a life controlled by spirit (in some places, the Holy Spirit).  Not all the references to a spirit lead life are direct references to the Holy Spirit but rather to the new spirit (= mind) of the converted Christian that has its source in the Holy Spirit.  See 1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18.

Important Note: The above is logically and theologically tidy but the New Testament frequently uses the terms “conversion”, “repentance” and “Christian life” as synonyms for each other.

**Glorification**

The term “glorification” as a noun does not appear in the Scriptures but is another modern theological term to describe what happens when God returns to rapture the saints.  It is also called “translation”, “rapture”, “resurrection of the saints”, etc, in modern terminology.  (See 1 Thess 4:16, 17, 1 Cor 15:12-56).  This is, when the mortal shall put on immortality and the corruption shall be made incorruptible and we shall live forever with Jesus.  Acts 23:8, Matt 22:30, Mark 12:25, Luke 20:36.

Comment: The words 'atone' and 'atonement' never occur in the Greek scripture. The single occurrence in the KJV is a misrepresentation of καταλλαγην. But the word cannot be used as an overall description of the content of the gospel. Nor can (as the question suggests) the word 'redemption'. _Kaphar_ in the Hebrew has a very specific meaning (_kaph_ the hand). That also does not mean 'atone' - a peculiar English word with a distinct lack of etymology that means only what it says (at-one-ment).

Comment: That is what the above answer says.  But it is modern term that has a general theological meaning.  The NT does not have a single word for it but many "analogues" like, justification, forgiveness, propitiation, expiation, credit, impute, gift, manumission, reconciliation, rescue (save), wash away, etc.  Some try to make one of these analogues do the work of all of them but that is misleading.

Comment: We actually need two English words, not one, for what is generally called 'redemption' since there are two distinct sets of words in the Greek, the 'lutron' group and the 'agorazo' group. I assume this goes back to Tyndale or maybe to the Wycliffe to group the two sets together under one expression.

Comment: The idea of "buying back", or more correctly, manumission is only one of a dozen ways of discussing the atonement as shown above.  “exagerazo” and “lutroo” are used almost interchangeably in the NT and 1st century Greek.  But this ignores, "logizomai", and "sozo" and "dike" and "hilasterion" and "apiemi", etc, etc.

Comment: My understanding of 'redemption' is 1. a dispossession 2. an acquiring 3. a securing and 4. the provision of a permanent sanctuary. And in the background is 5. the concept that the item always was the rightful possession of the redeemer. (The concept of _gaal_ the 'kinsman redeemer' of Ruth.) _Apolutrosis_ expresses the reversion of affairs to a previous situation that only ever existed in the mind of God in eternity. _Logizomai_, _hilasterion_ and _apo-iemi_, are different aspects of the whole doctrine of Christ.

Comment: Quite correct.  That is the point.  The Bible uses all these analogues to teach about different aspects of atonement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, Mr Salah--no offense--that you've 'never' read the Bible. No offense. Paul, for example, always is interceding for the saints.

I bow my knees unto the Father, of whom every family in the heavens and on earth is named, that He would grant you, according to the riches of His glory, to be strengthened with power through His Spirit into the inner man, that Christ may make His home in your hearts through faith, that you, being rooted and grounded in love, may be full of strength to apprehend with all the saints what the breadth and length and height and depth are and to know the knowledge-surpassing love of Christ, that you may be filled unto all the fullness of God. Eph 3. There it's for strength.

Unceasingly pray. 1 Thes 5:17. Do not cease giving thanks for you, making mention of you in my prayers. Eph 1:16. We thank God always concerning all of you, making mention of you in our prayers. 1 Thes 1:2. I thank my God always, making mention of you in my prayers. Philemon 4. Is it the word "saints" that you don't understand? Do you realize that a saint could sin? If anyone sees his brother sinning a sin not unto death, he shall ask and he will give life to him. 1 Jn 5:16. May I ask: how, in Salah's logic, could it be **illogical** for Christ to intercede for His saints? Do you know that intercession is prayer?

**Are all stages of Redemption assembled in these four verses?** I'd use the term "salvation" instead of "redemption," Mr Salah. For it has a permanent initial aspect. For with the heart there is believing unto righteousness, and with the mouth there is confession unto **salvation.** Rm 10:10. One's human spirit is saved, 1 Cor 5:5. It has a current daily continuing aspect. So then, my beloved, even as you have always obeyed, not as in my presence only but now much rather in my absence, **work out your own salvation.** Philip 2:12. And it has a future aspect. Receiving the end of your faith, the salvation of your souls. 1 Pet 1:9.

(One can summarize that believers are saved spirit, then soul, then body. Saved in the divine life. Rm 5:10. This is a massive subject. Along with God's eternal purpose: the very subject of the Bible.) The word "redemption" here, however, as applied to us personally, seems to be 'limited' to forgiveness, when a person first receives and believes into the Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God. We have redemption through His blood, the forgiveness of offenses. Eph 1:7. (Without the shedding of blood, there is no forgiveness. Heb 9:22; Lev 17:11.) And it's used for the future transfiguration of all His believers, which is redemption in a different sense. We ourselves groan in ourselves, eagerly awaiting sonship, the redemption of our body. Rm 8:23.

In the truest sense, both salvation and redemption (and everything positive) is Jesus Christ, God's Son. Lk 2:30; 1 Cor 1:30; Col 2:2-3; Jn 14:6; 15:5.

Comment: I try to understand the Bible by logic, How a saint be a Sinner?, If a Saint could be a Sinner then what is the criterion of sainthood?

Comment: You may be influenced by the common, or the Roman Catholic, use of the word "saint." In the New Testament (and Old) it's simply derived from the word "set apart." "Holy." Referring to all the chosen people of God. "To the church of God which is in Corinth, to those who have been sanctified in Christ Jesus, the called saints, with all those who call upon the name of our Lord Jesus Christ in every place, who is theirs and ours," 1 Cor 1:2. As for sin, please see or consider the thought in 1 Jn 1:7--2:2. The criterion for sainthood is faith into Christ.

Answer (score 0):

Because everything that Jesus accomplished for us at Calvary is applied by the working of the Holy Ghost, who is God dwelling in us. He makes real in us what was done at Calvary and the things that God provide are revealed by his Spirit thus intercession.
One that acts/ pleads on behalf of another. and furthermore even we ourselves don't know how to pray as we ought but the Spirit maketh intercession for us.